# Kubernetes Namespace Env Headers

Tags: php, docker, kubernetes

I have noticed that Kubernetes adds all the workloads on the namespace into the PHP/Enviroment variables.

Example: 
_ENV["WORKLOAD_XXX_LB_PORT_80_TCP_ADDR"]
_ENV["WORKLOAD_XXX_LB_PORT_80"]

Is there any way to remove those variables?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is no.

However, you can add something like this to your container entry script:

```
env -i bash
```

or

```
for c in $(printenv | cut -d '=' -f 1); do unset $c; done
```